Kafka message not produced using StreamBridge during integration testing with Kafka Testcontainer

spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        logging:
          level:
            org.springframework.cloud.stream: DEBUG
            org.apache.kafka: DEBUG
        binder:
          producerproperties:
            retries: 5
          autoCreateTopics: false
          brokers: ${KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS}
          defaultBrokerPort: 9092
          minPartitionCount: 1
          autoAddPartitions: false
          configuration:
            security.protocol: PLAINTEXT
            sasl.mechanism:
            sasl.jaas.config:
      bindings:
        output:
          destination: test-topic
          contentType: application/x-protobuf
          producer:
            useNativeEncoding: true
            partitionCount: 1
            requiredGroups: test-group
            configuration:
              key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
              value.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer

@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"test","h2","kafka"})
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = {Application.class})
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)

public class KafkaPublisherTest {

    @Autowired
    StreamBridge streamBridge;

    @Container
    static KafkaContainer kafka = new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest"));

    static {
        kafka.start();
    }

    @DynamicPropertySource
    public static void initKafkaProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", kafka::getBootstrapServers);
        registry.add("spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.security.protocol", () -> "PLAINTEXT");
        registry.add("spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers", kafka::getBootstrapServers);

    }

    @BeforeEach
    void setUpConsumer() {
        
        Properties consumerProps = new Properties();
        consumerProps.put("bootstrap.servers", kafka.getBootstrapServers());
        consumerProps.put("group.id", "test-group");
        consumerProps.put("key.deserializer", ByteArrayDeserializer.class.getName());
        consumerProps.put("value.deserializer", ByteArrayDeserializer.class.getName());
        consumerProps.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");

        consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerProps);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSendAndReceive() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

        byte[] messagePayload = "Hello Kafka!".getBytes(); 
        Message<byte[]> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(messagePayload).build();

        System.setProperty("KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS", kafka.getBootstrapServers());

        AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(Map.of(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafka.getBootstrapServers()));
        NewTopic topic = new NewTopic("test-topic", 1, (short) 1);
        adminClient.createTopics(Collections.singletonList(topic)).all().get();
        ConfigResource topicResource = new ConfigResource(ConfigResource.Type.TOPIC, "test-topic");

        
        ConfigEntry retentionEntry = new ConfigEntry("retention.ms", String.valueOf(604800000L));
        AlterConfigOp alterConfigOp = new AlterConfigOp(retentionEntry, AlterConfigOp.OpType.SET);

        
        adminClient.incrementalAlterConfigs(Collections.singletonMap(topicResource, Collections.singletonList(alterConfigOp))).all().get();

       
        try {
            boolean result = streamBridge.send("output", message);
            if (!result) { 
                System.err.println("Failed to send message");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Thread.sleep(5000);
      

        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("test-topic"));
        ConsumerRecords<byte[], byte[]> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        System.out.println(records.count());

    }


I’m using Spring Cloud Stream to produce Kafka messages in my application, but the messages are not being delivered to the intended topic. The StreamBridge.send method returns true, indicating successful execution, yet the messages don’t appear on the expected topic.
Interestingly, when I produce a message to the topic manually using the Kafka CLI, the consumer set up in the test class is able to consume the message without issues. This suggests the topic and consumer configuration are correct. Any insights into why messages from StreamBridge are not reaching the topic would be appreciated."
